# Change Background Image on NavBar Click

Tags: html, css, image, background, background-image

I have to admit I'm very new to this, but I'm building a website based on a template am just about done except for one thing! I'm trying to get the background to change to a different image when a user clicks on a nav bar item and a different part of the site pops up.

If it's helpful, this is the website: www.pitchadvisor.com

Currently, my nav bar links are set up as follows:

```
<a href="#!/page_about"><span></span>What</a></li>
```

I tried the following change but it didn't work:

```
<a href="#!/page_about" onclick="document.getElementById('test').style.backgroundImage='url(http://www.pitchadvisor.com/images/bg2.jpg)'; return false;" >
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!!

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its not working because, your background is set in html not css, heres what i came up with to possibly fix it:

Change line 78 of the html from

```
<div id="bgStretch"><img src="http://pitchadvisor.com/images/bg.jpg" alt=""></div>
```

to

```
<div id="bgStretch"><img id='bgimage' src="http://pitchadvisor.com/images/bg.jpg" alt=""></div>
```

and change your javascript from

```
<a href="#!/page_about" onclick="document.getElementById('test').style.backgroundImage='url(http://www.pitchadvisor.com/images/bg2.jpg)'; return false;" >
```

to

```
<a href="#!/page_about" onclick="document.getElementById('bgimage').setAttribute('src', 'http://www.pitchadvisor.com/images/bg2.jpg');" >
```

Let me know if this works for you, or anything else i can do.

Comment: thanks corvin, this worked perfectly! really appreciate the help!!

Comment: actually, sorry to be a pain, but one follow-up question: just wondering if its a huge task to make the transition between these images a bit smoother. at the moment its a very quick change between them, and I'm wondering if there's an easy fix for it. if not, no worries, its not a huge problem, just thought i'd check in case its relatively easy :-) thanks again!

Comment: Yeah, ill take a look at your code again, see if i can slow it down so it will come in near the middle or the end of the animations.
You can come talk to me on irc at #corvinm@irc.esper.net, if u dont have an irc client u can use this online one: http://chat.mibbit.com/?channel=%23corvinm&server=irc.esper.net

Comment: @python_rookie You can do transitions by using a package such as jQuery, or using CSS3 transitions. Since I'm typing... I also wouldn't stick that `<img...>` tag, I would use CSS `div#bgStretch { background: ... ; }` and I would not **ever** put inline `onclick` handlers in like this. Learn to attach event handlers via a separate `.js` file.

Answer (score 0):

Will this help?

```
    <a href="#" onclick="javascript:document.getElementById('asd')
.style.backgroundImage='url(http://www.pitchadvisor.com/images/bg2.jpg)';"> 
Click Me </a>

    <div id="asd" style="margin-top:50px; width: 100px; height: 100px; border: 1px dashed green;"></div>
```

Try it here: http://jsfiddle.net/dTAW3/